# How can use a variable of a object which is created by the user ?(Java)

Tags: java, input, methods, constructor, arguments

I created a class and left it on the user to make an instance. The instance has a constructor that requires the user to input values to the instance :-

```
public class perfo2{
     public int c;
     public int p;
     public int b;  
     public String n;
     perfo2(int c,int p,int b,String n){              //constructor
         this.c=c;
         this.p=p;
         this.b=b;
         this.n=n;
}
```

Now i have a few methods that requires variable from the instance like:-

```
   public  int calculate(int c,int p,int b){
        int per= (int)((c+p+b/60*100)); 
        return per;
    }
   public  void  dis(int c,int p,int b,String n,int per){
        System.out.println("Name:"+n);
        System.out.println("Chemistry:"+c);
        System.out.println("Physics:"+p);
        System.out.println("Biology:"+b);
        System.out.println("Percentage:"+per+"%");

    } }
```

now i want these methods to actually access the object for it various variables and use them.
I know what arguments i have given to the methods wont be able to that but what  will? and also 
if i make an object in the code itself i can easily access the variables by

```
michael.dis(michael.c,michael.p,michael.b,michael.n,michael.calculate(michael.c,michael.p,michael.b));
```

Comment: You probably just want to pass the object as a parameter like the following

public void dis(perfo2 perfo)

Then you can define the variables like perfo.n or perfo.c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a object and use it

```
perfo2 michael = new perfo2(c,p,b,n);

 michael.dis(michael.c,michael.p,michael.b,michael.n,michael.calculate(michael.c,michael.p,michael.b));
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly; you want to be able to access the varaibles set in the consructor `c, p, b, n`. You should be able to do this by creating getters on each of the variables as such:

```
public class perfo2 {
  public int c; // consider making the access modifier for c,p,b & n private
  public int p;
  public int b;
  public String n;

  perfo2(int c, int p, int b, String n) {   //constructor
    this.c = c;
    this.p = p;
    this.b = b;
    this.n = n;
  }

  public int getC() {
    return c;
  }

  public int getP() {
    return p;
  }

  public int getB() {
    return b;
  }

  public String getN() {
    return n;
  }
}  

// Create the object as such 
perfo2 person1 = new perfo2(1,2,3,"my String");
int c = person1.getC();
int p = person1.getP();
int b = person1.getB();
String n = person1.getN();
```

You may also want to consider making the access modifier for `c,p,b` & `n` private; therefore this cannot be accessed direclty from the object. Depedning on use case you could also use `person1.c` etc

Answer (score 0):

A bit extra code to my comment, you could use your class like this example. You could probably add the percentage to your class variables but i did not want to mess with your logic

```
public class Perfo2 {
   private int c;
   private int p;
   private int b;
   private String n;

   Perfo2(int c, int p, int b, String n) { // constructor
      this.c = c;
      this.p = p;
      this.b = b;
      this.n = n;
   }

   public int calculate(Perfo2 perfo2) {
      return (perfo2.c + perfo2.p + perfo2.b / 60 * 100);
   }

   public void dis(Perfo2 perfo2,int per) {
      System.out.println(perfo2);
      System.out.println("Percentage:" + per + "%");
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
      return String.format("Name: %s%nChemistry: %s%nPhysics: %s%nBiology: %s", this.n ,this.c,this.p,this.b);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Perfo2 p = new Perfo2(10,6,5,"Mark");
      p.dis(p, 70);;

   }
}
```